# Method to determine the coefficient of all variable?

Tags: regression, correlation, anova

I have a dataset with all category variables. From my understanding, I can use multiple linear regression to get the relative coefficients of A, B, C. However, I cannot get the coefficients of each value A1, A2, etc., since there are always omitted parameters(because I used dummy variables).

Example: Dataset

```
A = [A1, A2, A3, A4]
B = [B1, B2, B3]
C = [C1, C2]
```

Use dummy variable to code the category A, B, C, omitted parameter: A1, B1, C1.
The model:

```
y = CA2*X2 + CA3*X3 + CA4*X4 + CB2*X5 + CB3*X6 + CC2*X7 + N
```

With CA, CB is the Coefficient of the variables.

After regression, I can get the coefficients of A2, A3, B2, B3, etc., as compared with the omitted parameter(or the base group)

So how can I get the coefficients of all A1, A2, B1, C1, etc., value? What method can I use? I'm working on Python.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the question. Yes there's a reference category if you're using dummy codes. You're looking for the value of the regression coefficients associated with these dummy variables, or the correlation between variables? I think you should clarify your use of the word correlation, and maybe a numerical example (say, an example output) would help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will edit my question for clarity

Comment: The intercept contains the fitted/predicted value if all your categorical predictors are set to the reference value. The coefficients give the offsets if one or more predictors are set to a different value. Does that help?